# HttpSessionListener uma unica sessão por usuário

Tags: java, spring, jsf-2.2, http, http-request

Como consigo fazer com que **somente uma sessão http fique aberta** por usuário no sistema.

Principais tecnologias no projeto:

1. Spring 4
2. JSF 2.2
3. Hibernate 5

**Exemplo:**
O usuário juca, trabalha em seu computador usando 3 browser.
(I.e, Firefox e Chrome)

- Se ele logar com os 3 a mesmo tempo dentro de 1 minuto
- A sessão é de 1 hora
- Juca saiu para uma reunião
- Terei 3 sessões para o juca durante uma 1 sem fazer nada.
- Ou pelo 2 desperdiçadas (**ele pode trabalhar somente é um browser, isso é requisito do sistema**)
- Estou tentando usar HttpSessionListener, para controlar e invalidar primeira depois a segunda sessão.
- Ou seja só deve, permanecer a ultima logada.

Mas não estou vendo uma forma fácil de fazer isso.
(Como recuperar a sessão anterior em si não tem relação)

Alguém tem um conceito mais claro que resolva isso?

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendo a você usar [spring-security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). Esse trecho da [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions) mostra como usar **Concurrent Session Control**, que é o que você precisa.

Comment: Postei a questão no stackoverflow em ingles [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40218149/how-to-get-old-session-http-that-same-user) e encotrei a solução aqui

Comment: [Solução](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372311/how-to-invalidate-an-user-session-when-he-logs-twice-with-the-same-credentials?rq=1)  na resposta que **public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener**